# Select global variable by string, including sub-properties

Tags: javascript, object, eval

In javascript, I want to select a certain property by it's name, which is stored in a string. I know that `window[someString]` is the way to go. It works when `someString = "somevariable"`, but unfortunately, my program will also have strings such as `someobject.someproperty`. This does not work.

So the question is, given code

```
someString = "one.two.three";
one = {
  two: {
    three: "This is the value that I want to get"
  }
};
// window[someString] does not work.
```

, how can I get the value of `one.two.three` using the value of `someString`, *without* using `eval`?

Comment: I can't help with the answer, but I must honestly say in 30 years I've never seen anyone doing this. What kind of project is this? I'm just curious is all.

Comment: Trying to create something like an MVC framework, but now quite: I have code that sets `someobject.someproperty`, and then an element has `data-contents="someobject.someproperty"`. The code finds each of those elements and sets their content to the value of that which is specified in `data-contents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use split and make a recursive method

```js
var someString = "one.two.three";
var keys = someString.split('.');

one = {
  two: {
    three: "This is the value that I want to get"
  }
};

function getinnerProperty(object, keys) {
  var key = keys.shift();

  if (keys.length) {
    var nestedObject = object[key];
    return getinnerProperty(nestedObject, keys);
  } else {
    return object[key];
  }
}

console.log(getinnerProperty(window, keys));
```

Comment: This is what I assumed I would have to do. I was trying to avoid this sort of thing and find a short way, but I guess there isn't one. Your solution works recursively, so I chose it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that uses `split` and iteratively traverses the object tree:

```
var someString = "one.two.three";
var one = {
  two: {
    three: "This is the value that I want to get"
  }
};

function getValue(keyStr) {
  var keys = keyStr.split('.');
  var result = global;
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    result = result[keys[i]];
  }
  return result != global ? result : undefined;
}

getValue(someString);
```